# Запрет на обновление страници

Tags: webbrowser, mobile, swipe, page, pwa

Проблема вот в чем.
Я делаю рисовалку в телефоне (не важно), но при рисовании на холсте случаются моменты **обновления страницы свайпом вниз**. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как отключить этот свайп?**

(*Подойдет решение связанное с PWA.*)

Answer (score 0):

Сам нашел способ. Если поставить full screen mod
то функции браузера блокируются .

[здесь можно найти информацию как сделать full screen(w3)](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.asp)